# Laravel 5.3, Eloqent models and Namespace Issues

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am confused.  I am following the laravel document to the T and something isn't being configured properly maybe?

The Short: I can't use my Eloquent models like the documentation shows.

The Long:

I followed these steps from the Laravel docs.

1. laravel new blog
2. added database details to .env
3. created a model: `php artisan make:model SavedService`

   ```
   namespace App;

   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

   /**
   * @property integer $service_id
   * @property string $title
   * @property string $price
   * @property string $short_description
   * @property string $long_description
   * @property integer $display
   */
   class SavedService extends Model
   {
       protected $table = 'saved_services';
       public $timestamps = false;

       /**
       * @var array
       */
       protected $fillable = ['title', 'price', 'short_description', 'long_description', 'display'];
   }
   ```
4. created a controller: `php artisan make:controller datatest`
5. added `index` method to controller:

   ```
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use App\Http\Requests;
   use App\SavedService;

   class datatest extends Controller
   {
       public function index() {
           $flights = App\SavedService::all();

           foreach ($flights as $flight) {
               echo $flight->name;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Now, `use App\SavedService;` is highlighted in PHPStorm: "SavedServices is never used."

Also, for `$flights = App\SavedService::all();`, App is highlighted in red: "Undefined namespace App." SavedService is highlighted and PHPStorm tells me "Undefined class SavedService."

If I let PHPStorm create the SavedService class, its namespace is `App/Http/Controllers/App`

??

Project structure is

```
app
-composer.json
-Http\
-SavedService.php
--Controllers\
---dataTest.php
```

My `composer.json` autoload:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

EDIT:
Sorry, had to rush, train got into the station!  I wanted to add to this a few things.  First, I am using a vagrant machine to host the projects, not sure if that is important to know?  Second, I wanted to use Propel-orm.  I find eloquent not very eloquent at all.  I couldn't get propel to work, something to do with namespaces.  The propel generated models would be in app/Http/Models/Http/Models/ModelName.  I am beginning to think this is all one problem.

I am not doing anything extra ordinary to the process.  Just following the steps in the documentation.

Additionally, Eloquent doesn't seem to work the way the eloquent documentation hosted on the Laravel docs page.  For example "get()"  eloquentModel::get().  The laravel docs shows it as that, get(), and phpstorm throws a fit saying $key is expected.  The eloquent documentation confirms, get($key).  What am I missing there?  Why the difference, and why isn't it mentioned in the documentation.  Maybe this has something to do with my current issue?  Maybe the answer the this will solve why I can't use propel?

END EDIT.

What am I missing?  I'm so confused, why isn't this just working?  Help please!!!  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

change

```
$flights = App\SavedService::all();
```

to

```
$flights = SavedService::all();
```

Comment: That "worked"  Moving on to the next issue: $flight = SavedService::find(1); $flight->delete();   find and delete are highlighted: method not found.

Comment: Do you have a savedService with ID 1? I also don't see anything about your migrations here, did you make/run them?

Comment: No migrations, thought they were optional?  In this case, there is not a savedService with an ID of 1, but there is one with ID of 6.  Changing it to 6 doesn't change anything, still can't find the methods.

Comment: About removing "App\", why does the laravel doc show it this way, but in a real world use, it doesn't work?

Comment: you an use \App\SavedService, or you can just use SavedService, you just forgot the '/'.

If you're not using migrations, how did you create the table in your database ? Did you do it manually?

Comment: I did create manually.   I still question why I can't mimic the laravel doc 100%?  Thanks for the assistance, I hope that the train ride home I can move forward with this project!

Comment: @njDeveloper PHPStorm is just an editor. It tries to be as smart as possible, but it fails sometimes. There is a lot of magic in Laravel behind the scenes that PHPStorm just doesn't know about. Therefore, sometimes, PHPStorm will say a method doesn't exist, but it works fine. Also, you seem to have a lot of confusion over namespaces, so you may want to try and learn a bit more there. I would start with https://laracasts.com/lessons/namespacing-primer and [the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).